# Why is the default constructor the only one being used?

Tags: c++

I am triying to see when each method is called in this example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int x;
    A(int x) : x(x) {cout<<"default ctor"<<endl;}
    A(const A& a) : x(a.x) {cout<<"copy ctor"<<endl;}
    A& operator =(const A& a) {cout<<"assignment op"<<endl;x=a.x;return *this;}
};

A f() { return A(5); }

int main() {
    A a = f();
}
```

I expected the copy constructor to be called with the sentence `return A(5)` because as long as I know when an object is returned a temporary **copy** is created and returned. And also, in the sentence `A a = f()` I would expect the copy constructor to be called too because `a` is being initialized given another `A` object.

Why is `default ctor` being printed?

Comment: Compiler optimization. Note also, the litany of related questions shown on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two optimizations come into play here. [Return Value Optimization (RVO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) 
And [Copy Elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) will merge `f()`'s return value directly into the destination variable via initialization. So this code:

```
A f() { return A(5); }
A a = f();
```

Optimizes to essentially:

```
A a(5);
```

Comment: Oh interesting, however I think somewhere else someone said that even though optimization was performed, it was transparent and the output would be the expected. Anyway, would the copy constructors be the expected ones in both cases in case the optimization didn't happen? Just want to check I got my facts right.

Comment: Copy constructors and `operator =()` can both be elided. This is a good illustration of why it's important to follow convention when writing overloaded operators. For example if you tried to make `operator =()` do something other than a plain and simple assignment, you'd have this nasty surprise that your function call was removed.

Comment: however in the second case (`A a = f()`) the assignment operator is not the one that would be called, but the copy constructor. `a` is being initialized, not assigned different values than existing other ones, am I wrong?

Comment: Correct, in this syntax it will be compiled as initialization, not assignment. Updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Because c++ compilers are allowed to skip the `operator=` in cases of

```
A a = A();
A b = A(a);
```

and use constructors directly.
They are also allowed to perform Return Value Optimization for copy elision.

So in the end you have essentially `A a(5);`